# Delphi: how can i copy a text except for those between tags?

Tags: delphi, text, tags, copy, extract

Let's imagine i have a RichEdit with the following text:

```
<a> i want this <strike>i dont want sentences between "strike" tags</strike> <b> i want this </a></b> <strike> i dont want sentences between "strike" tags</strike>
```

So, I want to get the whole text but without the ones between "< strike>" and "< /strike>" tags, like this:

```
<a> i want this <b> i want this </a></b>
```

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using regular expressions. TRegEx.

Comment: The only bullet-proof method of doing this is to use a parser designed for the markup language being used (Html?).  Don't use regular expressions.

Comment: I replied as simple as the question was. He can also give a try to TJvHTMLParser (from JVCL).

Comment: @ZENsan:  Extracting strings from Html crops up regularly here on SO and the consensus seems to be that RegEx is not the correct tool and causes as many problems as it solves.  Details like the string to be recognised being embedded in a quoted text ...

Comment: I agree. The best and the fastest will be analyzing by character and setting the state like it's done in any known text parsers. But if you want quick solution I will write this task in 10 minutes with regex.. As there were no any requirements about unescaped tags or wrong formatting etc..

Comment: @ZENsan regex can't parse all well formed HTML as is very well known: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/

Comment: @ZENsan: "As there were no any requirements [...]"  Well, that may simply be because the point didn't occur to the OP, much like many SQL questions overlook the possibility that a column value may contain a single-quote.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I wrote "quick and dirty" - and it can do the task described by the author. And obviously once author adds more and more needs for his task, we need to do a proper solution and not regex.
But the main thing is that we are discussing there, but the author is not even responding :)

Comment: Why are you suggesting anything then? Far better to get the asker to engage.

Comment: I just wrote the first idea came to my mind. I was first who commented. And then others without author engagement starts discussing. I see that its better to not suggest at all.